# How to find out what object an NSControl is bound to via cocoa bindings

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm subclassing an `NSTextField` so that the user can increment/ decrement the integer value with the up and down cursor keys. It works fine via its delegate, but setting the user interface state via `setIntegerValue:` does not update the underlying value bound via cocoa bindings.

Instead of updating the control I need to update the model, so I need to find the object that the control is bound to and the key path that is used.

I can't find anywhere how to do this, so I've overloaded the `- bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` method of my `NSTextField` subclass, where the binding is established and where I can see both the observed object and its key path, but surely I'm duplicating information that is already available somewhere in the control..

Is there a way of obtaining the object and key path that a control is bound to via Cocoa bindings without hacking around like this?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way:

```
- (NSDictionary *)infoForBinding:(NSString *)binding
```

> A dictionary with information about binding, or nil if the binding is not bound. The dictionary contains three key/value pairs: `NSObservedObjectKey`: object bound, `NSObservedKeyPathKey`: key path bound, `NSOptionsKey`: dictionary with the options and their values for the bindings.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this but hadn't realised that I could just pass `@"value"` to get the right binding. Works fine now.